# Update Stock grep?

Tags: shell

stock.txt

Product: A  Stock: 1

Product: B  Stock: 2

Product: C  Stock: 3

I want to change the number of stocks of item b with any number? Should I use the grep command?

Comment: Grep can't modify the file for you.

Comment: Thank you i will try it well how can I remove the same line?

Comment: You can use sed, `grep -v`, awk...

Answer (score 1):

You want to use 'sed'

Something like this

```
sed -e 's/B Stock: 2/B Stock 10/' stock.txt
```

This will replace Stock 2 to Stock 10

```
Product: A Stock: 1

Product: B Stock 10

Product: C Stock: 3
```